# Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I want to execute a dynamic SQL statement, with its returned value being the conditional for an `IF` statement:

```
IF EXECUTE 'EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable)' THEN
```

This generates the error `ERROR:  type "execute" does not exist`.

Is it possible to do this, or is it necessary to execute the SQL before the IF statement into a variable, and then check the variable as the conditional?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This construct is not possible:

<strike>`IF EXECUTE 'EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable)' THEN ...`</strike>

You can simplify to:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable) THEN ...
```

But your example is probably simplified. For ***dynamic SQL*** executed with **`EXECUTE`**, [read the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS). You can check the special variable **`FOUND`** immediately after executing any DML command to see whether any rows here affected:

```
IF FOUND THEN ...
```

However:

> Note in particular that `EXECUTE` changes the output of **`GET DIAGNOSTICS`**, but does not change `FOUND`.

Bold emphasis mine. For a plain `EXECUTE` do this instead:

```
...
DECLARE
   i int;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT 1 FROM mytable';  -- something dynamic here

   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;

   IF i > 0 THEN ...
```

***Or*** if opportune - in particular with only single-row results - use the [**`INTO`** clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) with `EXECUTE` to get a result from the dynamic query directly. I quote the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> If a row or variable list is provided, it must exactly match the
> structure of the query's results (when a record variable is used, it
> will configure itself to match the result structure automatically). If
> multiple rows are returned, only the first will be assigned to the
> `INTO` variable. If no rows are returned, NULL is assigned to the `INTO`
> variable(s).

```
...
DECLARE
   _var1 int;  -- init value is NULL unless instructed otherwise
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('SELECT var1 FROM %I WHERE x=y LIMIT 1', 'my_Table')
INTO    _var1;

IF _var1 IS NOT NULL THEN ...
```

Answer (score 9):

Matt,

From the syntax above, you're writing PL/pgSQL, not SQL. On tht assumption, there are two ways to do what you want, but both will require two lines of code:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' || table_variable || ' );' INTO boolean_var;

IF boolean_var THEN ...
```

Or:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT 1 FROM ' || table_variable || ' );';

IF FOUND THEN ...
```

"FOUND" is a special variable which checks if the last query run returned any rows.

Comment: You are mistaken concerning `FOUND`. It is not set by a plain EXECUTE. See my answer for details.

Comment: Hah, that's what I get for answering quickly.

Answer (score -3):

```
SET @SQLQUERY='SELECT 1 FROM mytable'

EXEC (@SQLQUERY)
If @@RowCount >0  THEN
```

Comment: That's invalid for Postgres