# Count rows affected by DELETE

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I use this code to verify the `DELETE` sentence, but I am sure you know a better way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.sp_delete_row_table(table_name character varying
                                                       , id_column character varying
                                                       , id_value integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    BEFORE_ROWS integer;
    AFTER_ROWS integer;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || TABLE_NAME INTO BEFORE_ROWS;
    EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE ' || ID_COLUMN || ' = ' || (ID_VALUE)::varchar;
    EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || TABLE_NAME INTO AFTER_ROWS;

    IF BEFORE_ROWS - AFTER_ROWS = 1 THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 2;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

How to improve this code? I need it to work in Postgres 8.4, 9.1 and 9.2.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is incorrect. Consider the second answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the variables called `found` and `row_count`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS

`found` is true if any rows were affected. `row_count` gives you the number of affected rows.

```
IF FOUND THEN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
END IF;
```

Comment: EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE ' || ID_COLUMN || ' = ' || (ID_VALUE)::varchar;

Comment: GET DIAGNOSTICS AFFECTED_ROWS = ROW_COUNT;

Comment: IF AFFECTED_ROWS = 1 THEN RETURN 1; END IF;

Comment: Those statements could probably all be changed: `RETURN FOUND::int`;

Comment: Denis, I use FOUND after INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE sentences, but I can not use FOUND after EXECUTE. Because, EXECUTE changes the output of GET DIAGNOSTICS, but does not change FOUND.

Comment: Fair point. Btw, you should really escape the variables in those statements to avoid sql injections. Use `quote_ident()` and `quote_literal()`, per the docs on the same page I pointed you to.

Comment: Yes Denis, You are right: Now, I use: EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || quote_ident(TABLE_NAME) || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(ID_COLUMN) || ' = ' || quote_literal(ID_VALUE);

Comment: And, I use: IF FOUND THEN GET DIAGNOSTICS AFFECTED_ROWS = ROW_COUNT; IF AFFECTED_ROWS = 1 THEN RETURN 1; END IF; END IF; RETURN 0;

Comment: You are mistaken concerning `FOUND`, which is not set by `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you **cannot** use `FOUND` with `EXECUTE`. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

> Note in particular that `EXECUTE` changes the output of `GET DIAGNOSTICS`,
>   but does not change `FOUND`.

There are a couple of other things that might be improved. First of all, your original is open to SQL injection. I suggest:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.sp_delete_row_table(table_name regclass
                                                       , id_column  text
                                                       , id_value   int
                                                       , OUT del_ct int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format ('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %I = $1', table_name, id_column);
   USING id_value;                     -- assuming integer columns

   GET DIAGNOSTICS del_ct = ROW_COUNT; -- directly assign OUT parameter

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   del_ct := 0;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) requires Postgres 9.1 or later. You can replace it with string concatenation, but be sure to use escape the column name properly with [`quote_ident()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)!
The rest works for 8.4 as well.

Closely related answers:

- [Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: Yes Erwin Brandstetter, I use EXECUTE and after GET DIAGNOSTICS. I use only FOUN for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE sentences.