# Copy records with dynamic column names

Tags: arrays, postgresql, variables, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have two tables with different columns in PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
CREATE TABLE person1(
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE person2(
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL
);

INSERT INTO person2 (Name,    Age, ADDRESS, SALARY)
             VALUES ('Piotr', 20, 'London', 80);
```

I would like to copy records from `person2` to `person1`, but column names can change in program, so I would like to select joint column names in program. So I create an array containing the intersection of column names. Next I use a function: `insert into .... select`, but I get an error, when I pass the array variable to the function by name. Like this:

```
select column_name into name1 from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'person1';
select column_name into name2 from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'person2';
select * into cols from ( select * from name1 intersect select * from name2) as tmp;
-- Create array with name of columns 
select array (select column_name::text from cols) into cols2;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC _cols text[])
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT 'INSERT INTO person1 SELECT '
          || string_agg(quote_ident(col), ', ')
          || ' FROM person2'
      FROM   unnest(_cols) col
      );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select * from cols2;

  array    
------------
 {name,age}
(1 row)

SELECT f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC cols2);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  column "cols2" does not exist
> ```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to assume that `SELECT INTO` in SQL would assign a *variable*. But that is not so.

It creates a new **table** and its use is discouraged in Postgres. Use the superior `CREATE TABLE AS` instead. Not least, because the meaning of `SELECT INTO` inside plpgsql is *different*:

- [Combine two tables into a new one so that select rows from the other one are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559090/combine-two-tables-into-a-new-one-so-that-select-rows-from-the-other-one-are-ign/15560009#15560009)

Concerning SQL variables:

- [User defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)

Hence you cannot call the function like this:

```
SELECT f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC cols2);
```

This would work:

```
SELECT f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC (TABLE cols2 LIMIT 1));
```

Or cleaner:

```
SELECT f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC array)  -- "array" being the unfortunate column name
FROM   cols2
LIMIT  1;
```

About the short `TABLE` syntax:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)

### Better solution

To copy all rows with columns sharing the same name between two tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_copy_rows_with_shared_cols(
    IN  _tbl1 regclass
  , IN  _tbl2 regclass
  , OUT rows int
  , OUT columns text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO columns         -- proper use of SELECT INTO!
          string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ')
   FROM  (
      SELECT attname
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid IN (_tbl1, _tbl2)
      AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
      AND    attnum > 0        -- no system columns
      GROUP  BY 1
      HAVING count(*) = 2
      ) sub;

   EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %1$s(%2$s) SELECT %2$s FROM %3$s'
                  , _tbl1, columns, _tbl2);

   GET DIAGNOSTICS rows = ROW_COUNT;  -- return number of rows copied
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_copy_rows_with_shared_cols('public.person2', 'public.person1');
```

Result:

```
rows | columns
-----+---------
3    | name, age
```

#### Major points

- Note the proper use of `SELECT INTO` for assignment inside plpgsql.
- Note the use of the data type `regclass`. This allows to use schema-qualified table names (optionally) and defends against SQL injection attempts:
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- About `GET DIAGNOSTICS`:

  - [Count rows affected by DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798800/a-simple-affected-row-with-delete-in-posgresql/20808056#20808056)
- About `OUT` parameters:

  - [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)
- [The manual about `format()`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)
- [Information schema vs. system catalogs.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75124/3684)

Comment: It works: SELECT f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC (TABLE cols2 LIMIT 1)); Thx for help

Comment: @PiotrOlkiewicz: Consider the alternative solution I added.

Comment: Your function works perfect. Additionally I do not need to create temporary object. It is great solution. Thank you for help