# Test if anything was updated in dynamic query

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I need to construct and execute an `UPDATE` statement dynamically. Then I need to test whether anything was updated at all. My code is as follows:

```
DECLARE
  v_table_name text;
  v_column_name text;
  v_debug_flag boolean;
  v_upd_stmt text;
BEGIN
  select nm_table_name, replace(nm_table_name, 'CDB_', 'ID_')
    into strict v_table_name, v_column_name
    from m_entity e
    where id=12;

  v_upd_stmt := format('update %s set id_lock_usr =null, dt_lock=null where %s=$1 returning id_lock_usr',
                         v_table_name,
                         v_column_name);
  execute v_upd_stmt using p_id;

END
```

How to know if anything was updated?

Comment: You should provide a *complete* function. The header and other declarations are almost always relevant. And always your version of Postgres, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to know if anything was updated ?

Various options. In a plpgsql function, you can check the [special variable `FOUND`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) to see if the last SQL command affected any rows.

```
IF FOUND THEN ...
```

However, For dynamic queries with `EXECUTE` use **`GET DIAGNOSTICS`** instead. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

> Note in particular that `EXECUTE` changes the output of `GET DIAGNOSTICS`,
>   but does not change `FOUND`.

Related:

- [Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341)

**Aside:**
I see lingering problems with properly escaped identifiers (*especially* with upper case table names like you have), possibly even SQL injection. Fix with:

```
DECLARE
   v_table_name text;
   v_column_name text;
   v_id_lock_usr integer;  -- guessing the data type
   i integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT nm_table_name, replace(nm_table_name, 'CDB_', 'ID_')
   INTO   strict v_table_name, v_column_name
   FROM   m_entity e
   WHERE  id = 12;

   EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET id_lock_usr = null, dt_lock = null
                   WHERE %I = $1 RETURNING id_lock_usr'
                 , v_table_name,
                 , v_column_name)
   INTO v_id_lock_usr;  -- to store the *single* result from RETURNING

   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;
   IF i > 0 THEN
      -- do something
   END IF;
END
```

Note `%I` instead of `%s`.

In your case, if `id_lock_usr` returned by your query is `NOT NULL` (reliably), you might just test the result directly instead:

```
IF v_id_lock_usr IS NOT NULL ...
```

And you might want to schema-qualify table names to avoid ambiguities. But you must escape `schema_name.table_name` as two separate identifiers ..

Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: @VadBoro: Right, sorry, for dynamic queries with `EXECUTE` you need `GET DIAGNOSTICS` (as explained in the linked answer). I updated accordingly.