# Truncate if exists in psql function and call function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, truncate, search-path

I have the following code to create a function that truncates all rows from the table `web_channel2` if the table is not empty:

```
create or replace function truncate_if_exists(tablename text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    select
    from information_schema.tables 
    where table_name = tablename;
    if found then
        execute format('truncate %I', tablename);
    end if;
end $$;
```

Unfortunately I don't know how should I continue ...
How to execute the function?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I run the code, and I don't know what is the next step. How can I call the function with the right parameter. I get the message: _Function truncate_if_exists created

Execution time: 0.03s_

Comment: If I write `truncate_if_exists(web_channel2)` I get syntax error

Comment: Your code doesn't truncate "*if the table is not empty*". It truncates if the table exists - those are different things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### TLDR

To execute a Postgres *function* (returning void), call it with `SELECT`:

```
SELECT truncate_if_exists('web_channel2');
```

### Proper solution

> ... how should I continue?

Delete the function again.

```
DROP FUNCTION truncate_if_exists(text);
```

It does not offer any way to **schema-qualify** the table. Using it might truncate the wrong table ...

Looks like you are trying to avoid an exception if the table is not there.

And you only want to truncate ...

> if the table is not empty

To that end, I might use a ***safe*** function like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.truncate_if_exists(_table text, _schema text DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _qual_tbl text := concat_ws('.', quote_ident(_schema), quote_ident(_table));
   _row_found bool;
BEGIN
   IF to_regclass(_qual_tbl) IS NOT NULL THEN   -- table exists
      EXECUTE 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM ' || _qual_tbl || ')'
      INTO _row_found;

      IF _row_found THEN                        -- table is not empty
         EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE ' || _qual_tbl;
         RETURN 'Table truncated: ' || _qual_tbl;
      ELSE  -- optional!
         RETURN 'Table exists but is empty: ' || _qual_tbl;
      END IF;
   ELSE  -- optional!
      RETURN 'Table not found: ' || _qual_tbl;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

To execute, **call** it with `SELECT`:

```
SELECT truncate_if_exists('web_channel2');
```

If no schema is provided, the function falls back to traversing the `search_path` - like your original did. If that's unreliable, or generally, to be safe (which seems prudent when truncating tables!) provide the schema explicitly:

```
SELECT truncate_if_exists('web_channel2', 'my_schema');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b7012edb6137e697d4465fd5b95abf8e)*

When providing identifiers as *strings*, you need to use exact capitalization.

Why the custom variable `_row_found` instead of `FOUND`? See:

- [Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341)

Basics:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists/11892796#11892796)
- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)
- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)