# In a Postgres transaction, what is the best way to delete if exists, and fail otherwise?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

In Postgres, I want to do a bunch of deletes and writes in a transaction, but I want to fail the transaction if a row I am intending to delete does not exist. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where are you running your query from? A tool? App code? CLI? Please show some of your SQL so we can  better understand what you want to do.

Comment: Where you are using transactions? Because in PostgreSQL you can not use transactions inside the functions.  In Functions keyword "begin" means a "start transaction" and the keyword "end" means a "commit transaction". If your function has any type of exceptions then the transaction is automatically rollbacked. You can use transactions only inside the procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a PL/pgSQL code block (in a `FUNCTION`, `PROCEDURE` or `DO` statement) and raise an exception if your `DELETE` did not find any rows. You can use the special variable [`FOUND`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE id = 1;
   
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Failed to delete!';
   END IF;
   
   INSERT INTO tbl2 (col1) VALUES ('foo');
END
$do$;
```

Raising an exception rolls back the whole transaction.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

> Note in particular that `EXECUTE` changes the output of `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, but does not change `FOUND`.

See:

- [Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341)

Answer (score 0):

This idea will cause an exception if no row is deleted:

```sql
delete from mytable
where id = 123
and 1/(select count(*) from mytable where id = 123) > 0
```

This works by the subquery, which should have the same where clause as the delete's where clause, returning `0` if there are no matching row(s) to delete, which causes a divide by zero error that will automatically fail the transaction causing a rollback of all work.