# How to reset dynamic sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to reset a sequence value in PostgreSQL. If the sequence value is lesser than MAX value of a Sequence column then the sequence value has to be reset.

I tried with below code using dynamic query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test (
    schemaName VARCHAR
    , tableName VARCHAR
    , sequenceColumn VARCHAR
    , sequenceName VARCHAR
    , OUT result int
) AS
$func$
DECLARE
BEGIN    
  EXECUTE 'IF EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_sequences
    WHERE sequencename = '''||sequenceName||'''
        and last_value <> (
                            Select MAX('||sequenceColumn||') 
                            FROM ' ||schemaName||'.'||tableName||' 
                            )
    
    THEN


            SELECT setval(
                            '''||schemaName||'.'||sequenceName||'''
                            ,(
                                SELECT MAX('||sequenceColumn||') 
                                FROM ' ||schemaName||'.'||tableName||'
                             )
                        )
         '
  INTO result;
--END IF
   
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql 
IMMUTABLE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

--function call

```
SELECT fn_test (
        schemaName => 'schemaName',tableName =>'NameOfTable',sequenceColumn => 'Id_Column',sequenceName => 'id_Column_seq'
);
```

Currently I'm getting a error

ERROR:

```
 syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: IF EXISTS (
        ^
```

I'm familiar with handling dynamic queries in SQL server but facing an issue with PostgreSQL as I'm a beginner. Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Please check this syntax - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement

Comment: Thanks @Yeras_QazaQ that helped resolving my issue

Comment: 1) Why are you doing this? 2) The code has `and last_value <> (` which means the sequence value could be greater then as well as less then the `max(col_value)`. 3) I see this failing under any sort of load.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is SQL injection vulnerable. Never use pattern like  `... ''' || some | ''' ...`.

The code can looks like (with your argument names (see note bellow)):

```
DECLARE
  r record;
  v bigint;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO r
    FROM pg_sequences s
   WHERE s.sequencename = fn_test.sequenceName
     AND s.schemaname =  fn_test.schemaName;
  IF FOUND THEN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT max(%I) FROM %I.%I',
                   sequenceColumn,schemaName, tableName) INTO v;
    IF v <> r.last_value THEN
      PERFORM setval(format('%I.%I', r.schemaname, r.sequencename), v);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

- When you need to use dynamic SQL, then it should be short as is possible. The variables inside dynamic SQL should be sanitized always.
- The PL/pgSQL is not case sensitive language. This is reason why camel notation should not be used in this context. The identifiers `schemaname` and `schemaName` are same, and then there are identifier's collision. Usual convention is using snake notation, and when the routine contains some SQL, then PLpgSQL variables should to use some prefix (like `_`)